# How to sum the returned results in the same query?

Tags: php, mysql

How can I sum the sum-ed results (goal + delivered) in a new column, in the same query?

```
SELECT Sum(CASE 
             WHEN the_status = 'goal' THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
           END) AS goal, 
       Sum(CASE 
             WHEN the_status = 'delivered' THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
           END) AS delivered
FROM   the_data
where ....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just add a third column with both conditions:

```
SELECT Sum(CASE 
             WHEN the_status = 'goal' THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
           END) AS goal, 
       Sum(CASE 
             WHEN the_status = 'delivered' THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
           END) AS delivered,
       Sum(CASE 
             WHEN the_status IN ('goal', 'delivered') THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
           END) AS goal_and_delivered
FROM   the_data
```